# About create table as select (CTAS)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

When we do:

```
create table big2 as select * from big1;
```

Are the indexes and constraints also copied over to the new table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only NOT NULL constraints are copied.  See [FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/CTAS).

You can do `CREATE TABLE big2 (bigid PRIMARY KEY) AS SELECT * FROM big1` tp create a primary key, but yes, for other indexes you'll want to copy and run the index creation scripts.

Comment: Thanks. So basically before I copy the index creation scripts from big1 and run them after i create big2?

Comment: Edited to respond about indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for info, there is a simple way to remember indices to recreate them after deleting source table:

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl('INDEX', index_name)
    FROM user_indexes
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'BIG1';
```