# What is the most efficient way of creating a copy of a table with data and no constraints in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the most efficient way of creating a copy of a table with data and no constraints (Primary key and foreign) in Oracle? some thing similar to the below query.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS 
SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

It's fine if we need to drop the constraints manually after copying but the creation of copy should be quick.

Please advise.

Comment: how many rows in the table, what data types in the table, what hardware does the database have, what version of oracle,  most efficient is what: fastest?

Comment: What's wrong with the statement you have now (`create table t1 as select ...`)?  That should do exactly what you want.  It won't create any constraints on the new table.

Comment: Simply remove the parens. Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798727/about-create-table-as-select-ctas

Comment: FYI - a tip to create the table with NO data. Add this where clause to the select statement: `WHERE 1 = 2`. This ensures no data will be selected, resulting in an empty table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement the way you have it now is probably the most efficient way to do it. If not, it's pretty close.

It doesn't create constraints (apart from `not null` constraints) or indexes, so you have to create them manually after the operation completes.

You can specify that the operation should be parallelized by using the `parallel` keyword, though I believe that the feature is only available in the Enterprise Edition. Example:

```
create table new_table 
parallel
as
select * from old_table;
```

It's even possible to specify the number of threads to use by adding an integer parameter right after the `parallel` keyword. But, by default, it parallelizes according to the available CPUs on the server.

It is also possible to make the operation even faster by avoiding redo log generation.  This is done by specifying the `nologging` keyword:

```
create table new_table 
parallel
nologging
as
select * from old_table;
```

However, because no redo log is generated, the operation is unrecoverable. So, if you're going to use that, you should consider backing up the database immediately after the operation completes.  I would personally not use this option unless that extra performance is critical for some reason.

For more information on how to use the additional options with the `create table as select` statement, see the documentation: [CREATE TABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402).